# How to Solve a AU=B System when Determinant of A=0

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 & -1\\ -2 & -10 & 5\\ -2 & -10 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

and 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 15 \\ -15\end{pmatrix}.$$

To find a vector $U$ such that $A$ maps $U$ to $B$ then you must solve the system $AU = B$.

Isolating for U yields $U = A^{-1}B$

However, when attempting to solve the inverse of $A$ produces all $0$'s in the bottom row during matrix inversion algorithm, otherwise known as a determinant of $0$.

Comment: Avoid meaningless $U=B*(1/A)$ in matrix computations.

Comment: Is it instead (1/A)*B?

Comment: What is 1/A,  please?

Comment: Inverse of matrix A @dmtri

Comment: Write $A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Do you know the Moon Penrose invertible?

Comment: @dmtri I see your point.

Comment: I have imporved my answer by giving all the details.

Comment: @dmtri Moon Penrose->Moore Penrose

Comment: @Jean Marie,  yes you are right,  my typo.

Answer (score 3):

After Gaussian elimination we get a system in echelon form,

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&5&-1\\0&0&3\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\15\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

So by the second equation, $z=5$ and by the first $x+5y=5$. This is all you can say.

Comment: Matrix A reduces to {1,5,0}{0,0,1}{0,0,0} after gaussian elimination.

Comment: @sawreals2: and what is the right member ?

Comment: {1,0,0} on the right of the equation.

Comment: @sawreals2: this is wrong.

Comment: I see how z=5 is obtained here in the second equation as 3z=15 will reduce to that. But for the first equation why is it not x+5y-z=0?

Comment: @sawreals2: my bad, fixed. Your RHS is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that $\det(A)=0$. So $A^{-1}$ is meaningless. Nevertheless we can solve $Ax=b$ with $b=(0,15,-15)^T$ by, say, $x=(1,4/5,5)$. For this, we write $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and obtain three linear equations, namely
$$
x_1+5x_2-x_3= - 2x_1 - 10x_2 + 5x_3 - 15= - 2x_1 - 10x_2 - x_3 + 15=0.
$$
If we substitute $x_3$ from the last equation, we obtain $- x_1 - 5x_2 + 5=0$. With $x_1=5-5x_2$ all equations are satisfied.

Comment: That $x$ would not work for the first coordinate.

Comment: The solution is given without explanation and is… wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, it was a typo. Now I have also an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution of a square linear system $AX=B$ can be written

$$X=X_0+X_1$$

where :

- 1) $X_0$ is *a particular solution* of system $AX=B$.
- 2) $X_1$ is *the general solution* of the associated homogeneous system $AX=0$ (in more abstract terms : the generic element of the kernel of $A$).

In the case at hand,

1) has solution (see explanations below):
$$X_0=\begin{pmatrix}5\\0\\5\end{pmatrix}.$$

2) has solution
$$X_1=k\begin{pmatrix}-5\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}  \ \text{for any real} \ k.$$

Thus the general solution is

$$X_0+X_1=\begin{pmatrix}5-5k\\k\\5\end{pmatrix}  \ \text{for any real} \ k.$$

**Remark :** this formulation "particular solution of... + general solution of ..." is the same for linear differential equations.

---

**Explanation for (1) :** There are in fact many solutions ; here is a way to obtain one :

In system

$$\begin{cases}x&+&5y&-&z&=&0& \ \ (a)\\-2x&-&10y&+&5z&=&15& \ \ (b)\\-2x&-&10y&-&z&=&-15& \ \ (c)\end{cases}$$

Substracting (c) from (b), one gets $z=5$. Plugging this value in (a),(b) or (c) gives the same equation $x+5y=5$. It suffices then to take $x=5$ and $y=0$.

**Explanation for (2) :**

In homogeneous system

$$\begin{cases}x&+&5y&-&z&=&0& \ \ (a)\\-2x&-&10y&+&5z&=&0& \ \ (b)\\-2x&-&10y&-&z&=&0& \ \ (c)\end{cases}$$

Substracting (c) from (b), one gets this time $z=0$. Plugging this value in (a),(b) or (c) gives the same equation $x+5y=0$. It suffices then to take $x=-5y$.

Thus the general solution of the homogeneous equation is :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-5y\\y\\0\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix}-5\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Please note that, in fact, arbitrary constant $k$ is ordinate $y$.

Comment: At best this is a hint, but more appropriately a comment.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I am going to give explicitly the expression in the case at hand.

Comment: Can't you wait to publish the answer ?

Comment: Now it is a complete solution. But I was also in the spirit of the site by not giving the solution but a large hint in a direction that had an "added-value" compared to other solutions.

Comment: I am surprized of this downvote for a complete solution, but as the french proverb say "les chiens aboient, la caravane passe".

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not downvote, but am more interested to see theorems used than the answers.

Comment: @sawreals2 This is not apparently the point of view of some people here. One thing is certain: I have put forward the theorem used (sum of particular sol. + general solution of the equ. with LHs equal to 0).

Comment: I just cannot seem to grasp this. I've solved nearly 100 of these systems now and the solutions I get are not interger solutions.

Comment: Why should the solutions be integer-valued ?